# Unity Mac build becomes damaged after uploading

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I build a project in **Unity version 2019.3.4f1** and export as a Mac build I zip it and upload it to a site. When I download the app again it still works (asks for permission first, of course).

When I build a project in **Unity version 2020.2.x** and export as a Mac build I zip it and upload it to a site. When I download the app again it gives me an error message stating that my app is damaged.

[image]

Note: The app runs fine, before I zip it and upload it. It is only when I redownload the file that it says it has been damaged. I have tried this with many different export settings and with different websites including itch.io and slack. It always comes back with this message when I build with this Unity version. Even with a fresh project.

Why is this? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Same here. Any insight since then ? I found that the command in terminal "xattr -rc path/app.app" will fix the problem but I'm trying to understand how to not have to do that ...

Answer (score -2):

This might be a bug... Have you tried in 2020.1.x?